# Finding extreme point to a line segment

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I have a problem in computational geometry, Given $n$ points in 2d space, we want to preprocess the points in $O(n\log n)$ such that for each line segment query we find farthest point to that line in $O(\log n)$ and for solving this problem i think as follow  : find convex hull of input points in $O(n\log n)$, now, each of convex vertex can be farthest points to line query, but can i calculate farthest point to a line segment query in this situation $O(\log n)$?

Comment: What is the basic algorithm with no such limit? How you calculate the distance to segment/line?

Comment: I have no idea and get stuck in this step